# Cannot access wordpress hosted on localhost from my phone

Tags: wordpress, networking

What I have done:

1. Created an inbound rule in my firewall on port 80 for requests from local network
2. Modified Apache's httpd.conf and httpd-vhost.conf to allow requests from local network
3. Changed the Wordpress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) from localhost to my machine's LAN IP
4. Connect my phone to the wifi of the same router as my computer

What I can access from my phone:

1. My WAMP server homepage
2. The sample directory I created in my server's root directory

My problem:
Whenever I try to access the wordpress directory in my server's root directory from my phone the URL gets changed from my machine's IP address to 'localhost' and I am given the error message that the site cannot be reached. When I open my Wordpress site from my computer it is showing my IP without changing it to localhost. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because your pc knows the domain name for the IP address. You can check hosts file under C:\windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
Your phone also should know where to ask that domain name. And I advice you to set up a domain in your local. That could solve the problem

Comment: A good answer would explain all the steps and details. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: That is the loopback address in the hosts file. How does it affect Wordpress folder address when accessed externally exactly?